# Understanding the None output when using pandas.DataFrame.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to use the pandas.DataFrame.apply function. My actual code performs similarly to the example below. At the end of the output it outputs "None" for each row in the dataframe. This behavior causes an error in the function I'm passing through apply.

`df = pd.DataFrame({"one": range(0,5), "two": range(0,5)})`

`df.apply(print, axis=1)`

1. Why does it behave this way? What is the None coming from?
2. How can I alter/control this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `None` occurs because the `print()` function doesn't return any value and `apply()` expects the function to return something.

If you want to print the data frame, just use `print(df)`, or if you need some other format, tell us what your are trying to get at the printed output.

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot and resolve the issue. My function had an error that wasn't allowing it to return a value. Thanks

Comment: Totaly unrelated, but i printed df.info() which returns the info and None, turns out it doesn't need to be printed, it writes to sys.stdout.